# PowerShell script/command to export OneNote page names + URLs to JSON

Tags: json, powershell, scripting, onenote, onenote-api

For all OneNote notebooks that are syncing to my Win10 PC, how can I use PowerShell to generate a .json file that contains an array of objects, where each object contains:

- Notebook Name
- Section Name
- Page Name
- Page URL, using the `onenote:` prefix

...for every OneNote notebook/section/page in my current Windows user login?

The output would look like:

```
    [
      {
        "notebook_name": "My Notebook name",
        "section_name": "The name of a section",
        "page_name": "The name of a page",
        "page_url": "onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/...etc..."
      },
      { /* ...etc...*/ }
    ]
```

Comment: What have you tried/researched, what doesn't work as expected? [SO] isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a bit bored waiting on the OP, so here goes:

```
$oneNote = New-Object -ComObject OneNote.Application
[xml]$hierarchy = ""
$oneNote.GetHierarchy("", [Microsoft.Office.InterOp.OneNote.HierarchyScope]::hsPages, [ref]$hierarchy)

$result = foreach ($notebook in $hierarchy.Notebooks.Notebook ) {
    foreach ($section in $notebook.Section) {
        $sectionUrl = 'onenote:{0}' -f $section.path
        $section.ChildNodes | ForEach-Object { 
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                'notebook_name' = $notebook.name
                'section_name'  = $section.name
                'page_name'     = $_.name
                'page_url'      = '{0}/pages/{1}' -f $sectionUrl, $_.ID
            }
        }
    }
}

# clean up the COM object
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($oneNote) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

$result | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Hello @Theo, coudl this script be edited to download an entire OneNote as a Package? How would the script look like then?

Answer (score 0):

simplified to assist users with remapping their onenote notebookts after a tenant to tenant migration

```
$oneNote = New-Object -ComObject OneNote.Application
[xml]$hierarchy = ""
$oneNote.GetHierarchy("", [Microsoft.Office.InterOp.OneNote.HierarchyScope]::hsPages, [ref]$hierarchy)
$hierarchy.Notebooks.Notebook | select name,path
```